# Detect if google.maps.MarkerImage object is empty

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map that is being populated by several markers. I am getting my markers from http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_icon&chld=pin|glyphish_star|FFFF00|0000FF.  Some of my clients browser security prevents these images from being downloaded and i would like to detect this and revert them to a default image.

```
var gmMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=
    d_map_xpin_icon&chld=pin|
    glyphish_star|
    FFFF00|
    0000FF"
)
```

How do i detect if gmMarkerImage object is not a image or empty? Or how do i determine that I did not receive anything from the chart.apis.google.com site?

Comment: Try `console.log(gmMarkerImage);` and see what you get from the google, may be an object and some properties within it.

Comment: I have to use IE to view the page because of certificate issues. And i can't install third party apps. So my hands are tied when it comes to debugging with firebug.  It sucks but that is my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Google Maps API will not let you access the underlying DOM objects. The `MarkerImage` object you receive only contains the information about the marker, rendering it as HTML or DOM objects will read that information.

If we take one step back, though, the reason your users cannot use this custom URL for their images is probably that they do not trust the non-SSL reference (true?). Or that they don't trust the chart.google.com domain in general (this would be retarded, but still). You can test this by including an invisible image in your page not connected to the map and handle the `onError` event on this image. An `onError` on an image normally indicates that the resource could not be loaded, normally because of 404, 403, etc... When this image receives an error, you can iterate over all your markers and set their URL to the fallback.

Comment: This seems to be what i needed.  I will try the onError event handler. Thanks.